# What do the || symbols mean when working with sets?

Tags: notation, cross-product

I was doing research work for a paper that I need to write for my master studies and I came across the *cosine similarity* concept.

After a quick look in wikipedia there's this mathematical formula that I don't fully understand:

[image: Formula I found]

In my use-case we're working with sets of words (so called text strings) and the top of the formula is the *dot* product of the two sets.

What I've never seen is the `||` symbols for a set. I know that |A| stands for the cardinality of the set A but I've never seen the other symbol. Is it the same?

Comment: $||A||$ means [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm) of vector A

Comment: It looks like to me that $A$ and $B$ are vectors, not sets, and thus it would be their norm. In your case, you are looking at the angle between the two vectors $A$ and $B$, and that what you call the dot product is the scalar product.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am a computer scientist and these are "vectors" or "sets" (as my misconception) of words. How would I calculate the such "norm" on an array of words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) on "Cosine similarity" you mentioned says explicitly that $A$ and $B$ are vectors:

> [image]

---

For a vector $A=(A_1,\cdots,A_n)$ in the [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) $\mathbb{R}^n$, its "norm" is given by
$$
\|A\|:=\sqrt{A_1^2+\cdots+A_n^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your clarifications. I am working with arrays of words. How does it make sense to calculate an angle between two vectors of "words"?

Comment: @SomerandomITboy: you are welcome. The concept of "angle" between two vectors is well explained in this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product in particular this section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition

Comment: I've read more carefully. The authors of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309363405_User_identification_across_online_social_networks_in_practice_Pitfalls_and_solutions) translate the words into tf-idf values (which are numbers) and everything all of the sudden makes sense.

Thank you!

Comment: @SomerandomITboy you are welcome!